# Return void(0); vs return; interrupting functions

Tags: javascript

I ran across some code that interrupts a function `return void(0);`.

I believe that is being used to return `undefined` but that can be done simply by writing `return;`.

Does `return void(0);` serve an additional purpose, or is this just two different ways to interrupt a function?

Comment: not a duplicate for I already understand the meaning of `void(0);` and that it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Well, if you understand that `void(0)` evaluates to `undefined` what are you asking?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: The answer in the disputed dupe has a link to the MDN docs that explain exactly how that works.

Comment: @Jon his question is almost litteraly: Does it serve an *additional purpose* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return void(0);` doesn't do anything special. It simply returns `undefined`, albeit in a very silly way. It's probably a case of the original developer not understanding JavaScript fully.

Comment: More probably a case of OLD coding style.

Answer (score 4):

It's just another way to return `undefined`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void